# php split a day into number of times?

Tags: php

need a php function to split a day with number of times and get the right time.
for example if i split a day into 2 times

```
00:00:00
12:00:00
```

if I split a day ( 24 hours) in to 4 times it will show following

```
00:00:00
06:00:00
12:00:00
18:00:00
```

and if i split into 6 times output will be like

```
00:00:00
04:00:00
08:00:00
12:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
```

I need a function something like this

```
   <?php 
     function split_times ($interval) {
    //code
    return arry;
    } ?>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
<?php 

function formatSecondsToClock($seconds) {
    $t = round($seconds);
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60);
}

function split_times ($interval) {
    $result = array();
    if($interval > 86400){
        return $result;
    }else{
        $timeSlice = 86400/$interval;
        $timeStamp = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<$interval;$i++){
            array_push($result, formatSecondsToClock($timeStamp));
            $timeStamp += $timeSlice;
        }
    }
    return $result;

} 

print_r(split_times(6));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would work with timestamps and the `date` function. This way, you could simply split the day (86400 seconds) into `$interval` steps and add them to the time `00:00:00`.

Thats not that hard and everyone here likes to see some initial effort from the question author to help him and improve this approach. Keep this in mind for further questions. Stack Overflow is not an free coding service!

```
$start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
$steps = 11;
$step = 86400 / $steps;
for ($i = 0; $i < $steps; $i++) {
    echo date('H:i:s', $start + $i * $step) . "\n";
}
```