# PHP - Auto calculate time intervals in laravel

Tags: php

I have three columns in my table `start_time`, `end_time` and `interval`.

The `start_time` and `end_time` stores time like `22:00` and `24:00` respectively and the `interval` store time like `00:15:00`.

What I want to do is auto calculate intervals like `22:00 - 22:15`, `22:15 - 22:30` and so on till  `23:45 - 24:00`.

And if the `interval` is `00:30:00` the intervals should be `22:00 - 22:30`.

I'm new to laravel and stackoverflow so sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want as a result array with ranges or just array with elements

Comment: @Pyton result array with ranges like array:[0=>"22:00 - 22:15" 1=>"22:15 - 22:30"]

Comment: Can it go past midnight?

Comment: @Andreas No just till 24:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php split a day into number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472565/php-split-a-day-into-number-of-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop together with strtotime.

```
$start= "20:00";
$end = "22:00";
$int = 15;


$int *= 60;
$start = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);

for($i = $start; $i < $end;){
    $res[] = date("H:i", $i) . "-" . date("H:i", $i + $int);
    $i += $int;
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/I2lUS

EDIT; didn't notice you wanted a different output

Comment: @SarinKarmacharya Thank you! If you like the answer and it helped you, you can accept the answer with the tick mark left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$begin = new DateTimeImmutable('19:00');
$end = new DateTimeImmutable('24:30'); // Last 30 min will not be inclued (see output)
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M'); // Interval 30 min

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$ranges = [];
foreach ($daterange as $key => $range) {
    $ranges[$key] = $range->format('H:i');
    if($key>0) {
        $ranges[$key-1] .= ' - '.$range->format('H:i');
    }
}
array_pop($ranges);

print_r($ranges);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 19:00 - 19:30
    [1] => 19:30 - 20:00
    [2] => 20:00 - 20:30
    [3] => 20:30 - 21:00
    [4] => 21:00 - 21:30
    [5] => 21:30 - 22:00
    [6] => 22:00 - 22:30
    [7] => 22:30 - 23:00
    [8] => 23:00 - 23:30
    [9] => 23:30 - 00:00
)
```